# Servidor Apache/PHP não responde enquanto está fazendo uma requisição SOAP

Tags: php, apache, soap

Estou trabalhando numa aplicação PHP que consome um Web Service terceiro através de requisições SOAP. Porém algo que está atrapalhando é que enquanto uma página está fazendo uma requisição SOAP nenhuma outra página responde. Existe uma maneira de fazer a requisição recuperando possíveis exceptions porém sem ficar trancando a aplicação?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Provavelmente você está usando `session_start`, o *PHP* trava o arquivo (`LOCK`) de sessão, mesmo que você mude de página a sessão ainda é a mesma e o arquivo de sessão também.

> **Nota:** Outros visitantes da página não são afetados por "isto" (a não ser que você compartilhe a sessão) pois cada visitante tem seu próprio arquivo de sessão.

### Como isto ocorre

- Você requisitou a página `http://localhost/sync-webservice.php`, ela usa sessão e o tempo de resposta dela é de uma média de 10 segundos.
- Antes deste 10 segundos (tempo médio) terminarem o arquivo usado pela sessão estará travado.
- Ao acessar `http://localhost/profile.php` por exemplo (que também usa a sessão), a função `session_start` vai esperar o arquivo de sessão estar desbloqueado.
- Quando a página `http://localhost/sync-webservice.php` termina a execução a sessão é liberada para outras requisições acessarem o arquivo de sessão então a página `http://localhost/profile.php` vai detectar que a sessão está destravada e vai dar andamento.

### O que são arquivos de sessão?

Arquivos de sessão são usados para salvar os dados de uma sessão especifica, eles são gerados no momento do uso da função `session_start();` e normalmente são salvos na pasta `/tmp` como `/tmp/sess_2ognrumtg8pri1prd098r2vij0` por exemplo.

No conteúdo do arquivo de sessão `sess_2ognrumtg8pri1prd098r2vij0` por exemplo, contem os dados que serão usados na variavel `$_SESSION`, um exemplo de conteúdo:

```
nome-da-sessao|a:5:{...}
```

A cada vez que iniciamos uma sessão, se não existir o arquivo, ele é gerado, se existir ele faz a leitura, passa os dados do arquivo para a variável `$_SESSION` e trava o arquivo para gravação, no momento que a página completa a resposta para a requisição o arquivo é liberado para que outras requisições consigam usá-lo.

### Solução

Existem várias métodos que podemos usar, porém irei fazer referencia ao mais simples que é usar [`session_write_close`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-write-close.php). Note que só devemos usar isto quando não vamos mais setar nenhuma variável `$_SESSION[...] = ...;` ou usar outras funções `session_*`.

Exemplo de uso:

- `sync-webservice.php`

  ```
  <?php
  session_start();

  //Fazemos todas gravações necessárias
  $_SESSION['A'] = 1;

  //Liberamos a sessão do travamento de escrita
  session_write_close();

  /*
   A partir daqui não poderemos mais gravar nada na
   sessão, porém a leitura da variável `$_SESSION`
   ainda é acessível, pois ela é uma *super global*
   e já está setado os valores neste ponto
  */

  //Simulamos páginas "lentas", 15 segundos de espera (delay)
  sleep(15);
  ```
- `profile.php`

  ```
  <?php
  session_start();

  //Fazemos todas gravações necessárias
  $_SESSION['B'] = 1;

  print_r($_SESSION);
  ```

Desta maneira as demais página não irão precisar esperar a página *sync-webservice.php* terminar de processar para poderem completar a sua execução.

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode tentar thread, porém, thread em PHP é difícil, e depende de outras libs e da hospedagem. 
Sugiro criar um subdomínio apenas para fazer as requisições soap.
Acredito que isto será o suficiente para não travar outras páginas.
Caso continue, tente um servidor mais baratinho só para as requisições de soap externas.

Comment: Jonathan a aplicação se encontra em uma máquina dedicada Windows Server, não é hospedagem. Como toda aplicação é estruturada em torno dessas requisições não seria viável migrar "só" as requisições para outra aplicação.

Comment: Tente esta biblioteca, é curl non-blocking como vc precisa. Nunca usei, mas acho que vale tentar: https://github.com/stil/curl-easy