# Permitir múltiplas requisições do mesmo usuário PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Olá, estou trabalhando em um sistema legado desenvolvido com PHP. Este sistema funciona como uma single-page application utilizando jquery.ajax para carregar as paginas que o usuário solicita, cada pagina requisitada ao sistema é carregada em uma nova tab.
Em paginas de pesquisa dependendo do filtro pelo usuário o processamento pode demorar algo em torno de 30 ou 40 segundos para retornar devido ao volume dados no banco.
O problema ocorre neste caso citado acima onde usuário não consegue fazer mais nada no sistema até que a requisição da pesquisa seja concluída. Se o usuário tenta por exemplo abrir outra pagina ele não consegue porque o sistema ainda está processando a requisição anterior.
Gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira do PHP permitir multiplas requisições de um usuário, desta forma o sistema passa a permitir que o usuário carregue outras paginas enquanto a pesquisa é solicitada.

javascript utilizado na requisição

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'php/incluir_pesquisa.php',
            async: true,
            data: {
                tabID: documentoId,
                nomeDocumento: nomeDocumento
            },
            success: function (result) {
                $('#jqxTabs').jqxTabs(
                    'addLast',
                    'Pesquisar',
                    result
                );
            }
        });
```

Comment: Coloque o `javascript` que você está usando, mas acredito que seu problema resolva com `async:True`

Comment: **Relacionado:** [Servidor Apache/PHP não responde enquanto está fazendo uma requisição SOAP](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/56304/3635)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente isso ocorre por causa do `SESSION` ou `TRANSACTION`.

O PHP não limita de nenhuma forma o número de conexões simultaneas (o NGINX, Apache ou extensões ou outros firewalls, até podem).

### 1. Session:

O Session não pode ser acessado por mais de um processo em modo de leitura de gravação. Você pode ler por inúmeros processos, mas não pode escrever.

Logo:

```
session_start();

$salvaSession = $_SESSION['ultimo_acesso'] = time();
$lerSession = $_SESSION['usuario'];

 // Seu código demorado....
while(1 = 1){ // Um loop infinito para simbolizar algo demorado :P
}
```

Se fizer uma requisição irá impedir que qualquer outra requisição seja aceita, enquanto o loop for encerrado.

*Isso ocorre porque o `session_start` indica que a sessão pode ser lida e escrita, o que previne acesso de qualquer outro processo.*

Logo, para corrigir use:

```
session_start();

$salvaSession = $_SESSION['ultimo_acesso'] = time();

session_write_close();

$lerSession = $_SESSION['usuario'];

 // Seu código demorado....
while(1 = 1){ // Um loop infinito para simbolizar algo demorado :P
}
```

Pronto, a partir da "terceira" linha você já permite outro processo ter acesso ao mesmo session. Porque você diz para o PHP: "não vou mais escrever nada nesse sessão". Você ainda será capaz de ler após usar o `session_write_close();`. ;)

*Logo, após o `session_write_close();` a outra requisição poderá ser processada, o que não exige terminar o loop. :D*

### 2. TRANSACTION:

Isso é mais complexo e é relacionado ao banco de dados (não ao PHP). Dependo do nível de solamento usado no banco de dados ou das queries.

Por exemplo:

```
mysqli_begin_transaction($con);
mysqli_autocommit($con, false);

mysqli_query($con, 'SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = 1 FOR UPDATE');

 // Seu código demorado....
while(1 = 1){ // Um loop infinito para simbolizar algo demorado :P
}

mysqli_commit($sql);
```

Caso acesse novamente essa página, numa segunda aba, ele não será processado, porque o MySQL irá impedir a leitura da query enquanto não houver `UPDATE` ou `COMMIT`, isso irá depender da `Engine` usada, do `Banco de dados` usado e do nível de `Isolamento!

Comment: Exatamente estes pontos de gargalo que identifiquei na aplicação. Principalmente relacionado a sessão. Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Não resolveria colocar alguma ação enquanto carrega as requisições?

```
$.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'suaPagina.php',
        data : data,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function()
        {   
            $(".item").html(''); //<-- ação aqui

        },
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Felipe, não resolveria, já tentei por exemplo cancelar a requisição da pesquisa quando o usuário fecha a tab de pesquisa, mas mesmo assim a o servidor fica travado esperando a resposta do banco

Comment: Entendi, porém se você abre as requisições em outra tab, não seria melhor trabalhar com GET ? Ajax é recomendado no máximo em modais até porque é pré carregado antes do funcionamento, diminuindo o desempenho das páginas.

Comment: Sim, realmente esta alteração pode melhorar o desempenho da pagina, porém ainda não resolve o problema do que ocorre do lado servidor, onde não processa uma requisição até o termino da outra.

Comment: Felipe, se o servidor não responde, de nada serve enviar mais requisições.

Comment: Pelo jeito o problema é no async mesmo, não tenho conhecimento nessas funções, pelo que vi ela depende de um src="", pode ser que resolva seus problemas