# Abortar requisição AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, oracle

Estou com uma dúvida. Preciso cancelar uma requisição AJAX no lado do cliente e no lado do servidor.

No lado do cliente eu uso o `abort()`

```
var requisicao = $.ajax({ url : 'xyz.php'  });

if(requisicao && cliente_abortou_requisicao){ 
    requisicao.abort(); 
}
```

Agora no lado do servidor estou com dúvida. Como faço para o PHP parar de executar? Pois se só fizer no lado do cliente, o *script* ainda roda no servidor e se eu fizer outra requisição AJAX para o servidor essa requisição fica aguardando o término da requisição anterior.

Exemplo:

```
 <?php

      $DB = getConexaoOracle();

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM FUNCIONARIOS"; // 1 milhão de registros (exemplo)
      $RS = $DB->Execute($sql);

      $array_de_retorno = array();

      while($RS->hasNext()){
            ...
      }

      die(json_encode($array_de_retorno));

 ?>
```

Alguém saberia como faço para tratar que essa sessão foi abortada pelo cliente?

Comment: As requisições ajax duram entre 0.1 e 1 segundo em 99.9999% dos casos. Qual é o cenário que precisa desta funcionalidade? Não digo que não seja válida, mas seria interessante saber o problema para ajudar melhor na solução.

Comment: Eu estou usando uma requisição AJAX assincrona para realizar a impressão de uma relatório de pedidos.

Que dependendo do Representante, pode demorar até 5 minutos. Mas as vezes eles não querem esperar.

Comment: Isso pode ajudar, da uma olhada. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810339/how-to-cancel-a-php-process-when-ajax-call-is-cancelled

Comment: Teste adicionar "async: false" na sua chamada ajax.

Comment: Não parece ser o jeito certo de tentar resolver. Talvez essa outra pergunta lhe dê alguma luz: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164938

Comment: Daniel, salvar o resultado em cache não seria bom para mim, pois eu utilizo regras de price. Um produto X pode ter preço diferente por N variáveis ( estado, classificação fiscal, categoria, condição de pagamento, etc),  para exemplificar, uma consulta de 1 produto demora em média 1 segundo, se o usuário quiser pesquisar os produtos de uma Linha de produto que pode ter até 3 mil produtos se ele não especificar um filtro melhor, o sistema irá processar e ficar travado na requisição por 3 mil segundos. Eu queria poder dar a opção dele cancelar a requisição e refazer o filtro de forma mais ágil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos por etapa do problema, a sua solução para o problema (abortar o ajax no lado do cliente) não é a solução de fato, o problema está no server-side.

### Como faço para o PHP parar de executar?

O PHP por padrão interrompe a requisição sempre que o usuário desiste da página. A única codição para isto não ocorrer é se definir um [`ignore_user_abort(true)`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ignore-user-abort.php) ou se definir o valor em [`ignore_user_abort = 1`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/misc.configuration.php) no `php.ini`.

> [If the remote client disconnects, the ABORTED state flag is turned on. A remote client disconnect is usually caused by the user hitting his STOP button.](http://php.net/manual/en/features.connection-handling.php)

O problema é que quando se usa o `mysqli_*`, **por exemplo**, mas também deve ser aplicável ao seu caso, isso passa a ser fora do PHP. Basicamente o PHP não tem mais controle sobre isso diretamente. Mas, após *voltar ao comando do PHP* o processo será morto, *entenda que quando entrar em `$array_de_retorno` o processo será morto porque o usuário abortou*.

### Mas, porque se eu fizer outra requisição ele aguarda requisição anterior?

Isso provavelmente é o uso de [`SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) ou [`ISOLAMENTO`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)) (e também o `LOCKING` de tabelas) do banco de dados utilizado. A primeira situação é extremamente mais provável no seu caso (e na maioria dos casos). Existe também a possibilidade de está definido algum *rate limit*, que define quantas requisições podem ser feitas por cliente, isso pode ser definido no Apache/Nginx (e afins).

Mas, vamos ao mais provável, quando você faz isso:

```
session_start();
```

Irá bloquear a escrita e gravação na sessão, *que é um mero arquivo*, isso irá fazer com que qualquer outra requisição seja bloqueada.

Uma solução é utilizar o [`session_write_close()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-write-close.php) e assim permitir que **outra requisição** leia e grave os dados no arquivo da sessão, porque quando chama o `session_write_close()` indica que aquele processo não vai mais escrever nada, **mas ainda pode ler**.

[Veja esta resposta sobre esse mesmo problema.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153703/15089)

Comment: Olá, eu fiz um teste mas ainda não está parando o PHP, estou fazendo errado? segue o AJAX de exemplo ( https://jsfiddle.net/h6n8k4o8/1/ ).

Comment: O `fopen` está editando o mesmo arquivo, isso é exatamente a mesma situação do `session`. A sessão, como escrito acima é somente um arquivo, onde somente um processo pode edita-lo. O `fopen` está fazendo EXATAMENTE a mesma coisa do session, ou seja duas requisições para editar um mesmo arquivo. Se você faz uma requisição para editar `teste` e outra para editar o mesmo `teste`ele irá esperar o primeiro terminar, porque não pode dois processos editar o mesmo arquivo.

Comment: Utilize `fopen(bin2hex(random_bytes(5)).'.txt','w');` e veja se o problema persiste, isso irá fazer cada processo escrever um arquivo diferente, assim solucionando o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você faz uma requisição no front, a mesma é enviada pro servidor, que executa a operação, e quando você cancela antes do recebimento do retorno, você só deixa de recebê-lo mas a execução continua no servidor. Você precisaria reestruturar o seu código de back pra verificar se poderia continuar a execução ou não.

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo? Utilizando o exemplo citado.

Comment: Pro seu exemplo, acho mais simples e indicado que você utilize paginação com um botão logo abaixo da listagem (carregar mais). 
Creio que seria muito mais viável. 
Seria rápido e não haveria necessidade de cancelar a requisição.

Answer (score -3):

Tente adicionar um simples `break` (http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.break.php), ou `exit`(http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.exit.php) no código `php`

Comment: Poderia me dar um exemplo? Utilizando o exemplo citado.
Aonde e como que eu mando o sistema dar um break?

Comment: Use após a última linha que você gostaria que fosse executada

Comment: Ainda não entendi. Eu envio uma requisição ao servidor. Armazeno essa requisição em uma variável no JS. Quando o cliente aborta a requisição eu simplesmente pego a variável e chamo o médoto abort(). Mas lá no servidor ainda continua rodando, e o servidor não aceita outra requisição enquanto estiver processando. E com isso eu não consigo enviar alguma variável via GET ou POST dizendo ao servidor que a conexão foi interrompida pelo cliente. Entendeu?