# Salvar relatórios em uma tabela ou executar uma consulta ao banco de dados?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou montando um e-commerce onde possuo uma área para gerar relatórios de vendas. Esses relatórios são divididos por ano e mês.

Atualmente eu possuo uma consulta `sql` onde segmento os resultados por ano e mês e depois obtenho os resultados que desejo, por exemplo:

- Vendas

  - Total de vendas;
  - Total de vendas em R$;
- Produto

  - Lista dos produtos;
  - Produto mais vendido;
- Envio

  - Total de vendas enviado por correios;
  - Total de vendas enviado por transportadora;
- Pagamento

  - Total de pagamentos online;
  - Total de pagamentos com depósito;

E assim por diante...

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, como os relatórios são fixos, ou seja, quando o mês acaba não tem mais como alterar os dados daquele mês, seria melhor eu salvar uma tabela com os relatórios? Ou devo manter eles através de uma nova consulta e filtrar essas informações sempre que o usuário acessar a página de relatórios?

Ao fazer a consulta toda vez que eu preciso exibir o relatório, eu sinto que é uma consulta muito pesada e demorada, pois existem diversas tabelas relacionadas, por exemplo, `tipoPagamento`, `tipoEntrega`, `cliente`, etc..

Já cadastrando os dados de relatório em uma tabela, a consulta é mais simples, porém terei mais informações no banco. Obs.: Dentro do esquema de salvar em uma nova tabela, apenas a lista de produtos é que permaneceria através de consulta, pois iria gerar uma duplicação desnecessária.

Estou utilizando `PHP` e banco de dados `MySql`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Salvar os resultados é uma boa opção para otimizar pois é comum consultar várias vezes uma mesma condição. Por exemplo, consultar o mês inteiro é algo óbvio e comum. Isso poupa muito processamento repetitivo. Consultar uma quinzena ou semanal também é algo comum. Procure saber qual o "padrão" ou qual a frequência mais relevante dos usuários.

Claro que isso tudo não fará diferença para uma quantidade não muito grande. Digamos até 800 mil registros não terá tanta diferença. Mas é muito relativo afirmar tal número pois pode variar muito conforme o ambiente e complexidade das queries. O ideal (particularmente falando) é apenas observar. Quando perceber que está começando a ficar lento, é hora de otimizar.

## Exemplo de filtro estático

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso é o filtro de pesquisa da página do relatório de vendas do itunnesConnect (Apple).

Existem as opções estáticas "yesterday", "7 days, "30 days", etc.

Essas são as opções que provavelmente os usuários consultam com mais frequência e por isso provavelmente o sistema interno gera automaticamente o "cache" das consultas, retornando os dados com muita rapidez. E realmente retorna muito rápido, considerando o volume de dados que possuem.

Alternativamente tem a busca customizada onde o usuário define o período que quiser. Nesse caso, se o período escolhido não possuir nenhum cache, a consulta demora um pouco dependendo do período. Mas se repetir a mesma consulta, já retorna bem rápido pois é gerado um cache provavelmente.

Para um sistema pequeno com pouco volume não precisa se preocupar muito com isso. Pode ir implementando conforme a demanda. Na maioria das vezes é "em vão" construir algo otimizado logo de cara, sem saber se o projeto vai ter mesmo um grande volume.

As regras variam de negócio para negócio.
Aqui outro exemplo, do Amazon.co.jp

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Nesse do Amazon não tem opção de customizar o período. É tudo estático.

Quais regras de filtro estático escolher, é algo baseado em opinião, ou seja, depende do business model de cada caso.

Usei exemplos de duas grandes empresas para dar ênfase e mostrar que mesmo os gigantes aplicam esse método. Não existe mágica, por exemplo, usar fulltext, usar innoDB ou MyISAM, aplicar índices e chaves aqui e ali. Não faz tanta diferença. Mas a forma como monta as queries pode apresentar uma grande diferença tal como a modelagem. E obviamente as técnicas de cache de resultados.

Comment: O filtro em si vai ser somente mensal, pelo menos não existem planos de mudar para um método diferente de relatórios, até por que esses relatórios são administrativos da empresa. Mas gostei da expansão e considerações que você abordou, inclusive com exemplo prático.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo deixar o relatório através de consulta por SQL. Uma vez que seu relatório possa ter filtros de data inicio e fim, o usuário poderia acessar a qualquer momento e fazer as comparações necessárias.
Em relação as consultas, tentar otimizar o máximo sua query, mas não vejo problema nisso uma vez que é bem elaborado.

Em relação aos dados, teria que ter uma validação, talvez uma trigger para que não seja permitido alterar dados após um tempo específico.