# Destruir sessão específica no PHP

Tags: php, login

Estou construindo um sistema de login com Sessions em PHP, ele irá ter uma parte administrativa que mostrara todos os usuários logados no sistema. Minha dúvida é... Como posso deslogar apenas um usuário específico que esteja logado no momento ?

Comment: Você tem algo já iniciado? Como serão trabalhadas as sessões? identificadores? melhore sua pergunta, leia https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Você quer destruir a sessão de outro usuário em outro pc? É isso?

Comment: Isso, seria para destruir a sessão do usuário que esta logado em outro pc

Answer (score 1):

Uma ideia simples seria no momento que usuário se autenticar você salvaria o valor de `session_id()` em algum arquivo ou tabela de LOGONS, e no usuário "administrador" você teria uma página que receberia o valor do ID em algo como:

**`killusersession.php`**

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['session'])) {
    session_id($_GET['session']);
    session_start();

    $_SESSION['logoff'] = true;

    session_write_close(); //Fecha imediatamente o arquivo
}
```

Então nas páginas do usuário teria algo como:

```
<?php
session_id();
session_start();

if (!empty($_SESSION['session']['logoff'])) {
     header('Location: /login.php');
     exit;
}
```

Ou seja, o valor `$_SESSION['session']['logoff']` seria como uma flag para informar que ele não pode mais acessar, então em um novo login do usuário bastaria remover este valor.

É uma explicação bastante superficial porque realmente desconheço o seu código.

**Notas:**

Eu não recomendei o uso de `session_destroy()` porque ele pode causar resultado inesperados, ele pode causar [race condition](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/159342/3635), ou seja talvez gerar novos IDs (sessões no back-end/tmp) enquanto outras requisições, como imagens, ajax, etc estiverem rodando ao mesmo tempo, isto seria bastante complicado de ajustar.

As sessões em PHP pode causar bloqueios em requisições demoradas, por isso forcei o `session_write_close`, mas o problema também seria se o usuário logado estiver fazendo algo que ocupe o tempo, o que faria o `killusersession.php` demorar um pouco, conforme expliquei em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/57827/3635

Você poderia também criar um arquivo como flag, para informar quais usuários deveriam ser eliminados, isso não baseado na sessão, mas no ID, essa flag seria avaliada no sistema de usuário e em seguida removida, para evitar que em um próximo logon ela fizesse o logoff novamente, mas isso é muito amplo para sugerir aqui, depende muito do que você já tem pronto.